# Make Conditional Api Request Based On Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a minimalist landing page with two texts and one div, containing two buttons. On click of one of those buttons, I want to render the `App` component  with either the location passed as prop or the default one hard-coded into the `App` component.

I have gotten the location `using GeoLocation API and window navigator` and passed it into the `App` component if the first button was clicked like below:

```
if (this.state.shouldShowMain){
        return ( <App/> ) // no props
    } else if (this.state.shouldShowMainWithProps){
        const { lat, lng } = this.state.mLocation;
        return ( <App
            latitude={lat}
            longitude={lng} // props to App component
        />)
    }
```

my state object is like this:

```
this.state = {
        mLocation: {
            lat: '',
            lng: ''
        },
        isFromLocation: false,
        shouldShowMain: false,
        shouldShowMainWithProps: false
    };
```

and in App component I'm trying to distinguish between the two states before making an api call to fetch the markers like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {

    if (this.props){
        const { latitude, longitude } = this.props;
        // console.log(this.props);

        fetch(
            // 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll= 12.917137,77.622791' +
            'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + latitude + ',' + longitude +
            '&query=atm&client_id=LVN4FEBT5Q0DBIQ2JOP4KYZ1LOEXREFRLOXV5UXAQWHUF14V' +
            '&client_secret=HZRYTMFJRS4N0R50IEZR04JXSO1KWVJWC015VTYLCCCG3C0U&v=20181101')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

                const atms = data.response.venues;
                const markers = atms.map( (item) => {
                    return {
                        lat: item.location.lat,
                        lng: item.location.lng
                    }
                });

                this.setState({
                    atms,
                    markers
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({apiError: true});
                throw err;
            });
    } else {
        // no probs, fetching from silk board

        fetch(
            // 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + latitude + ',' + longitude +
            'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll= 12.917137,77.622791' +
            '&query=atm&client_id=LVN4FEBT5Q0DBIQ2JOP4KYZ1LOEXREFRLOXV5UXAQWHUF14V' +
            '&client_secret=HZRYTMFJRS4N0R50IEZR04JXSO1KWVJWC015VTYLCCCG3C0U&v=20181101')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

                const atms = data.response.venues;
                const markers = atms.map( (item) => {
                    return {
                        lat: item.location.lat,
                        lng: item.location.lng
                    }
                });

                this.setState({
                    atms,
                    markers
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({apiError: true});
                throw err;
            });
    }

}
```

The situation when I tested it is that, when I select the button for get my location, it fetches for the hard coded location in App component, i.e the else part and when I click on the button without props, the app crashes as it is expecting some value where there really shouldnt be one.

It is working in reverse case, therefore the api calls are failing. How do I fix this? I am willing to edit the question to accommodate any details requested. Thanks.

Based on the good suggestions, I have received that problem has been half-solved. The issue now is rendering the right map from coords. This is my implementation:

```
<div className="mapContainer">

                    <MapView
                        atms={this.state.atms},
                        markers={this.state.markers}
                        apiError={this.state.apiError}
                        filteredAtms={filteredAtms}/>
                </div>
```

where the markers prop in `MapView` is from the `then in response from api` and in `MapView component` I have this implementation for default center of marker:

```
const MyCity = withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultCenter={{lat: 12.917137, lng: 77.622791}}
            defaultZoom={15}>

            {/*{<Marker position={{lat: 12.917137, lng: 77.622791}}/>}*/}

            {this.props.markers && this.props.markers.map( (marker, index) =>
                <Marker
                    key={index}
                    position={{lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng}}/>
             )}

        </GoogleMap>

    ));
```

How do I adapt this? Do I use the same approach of setting default props on this component or another way. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the issue of fetching from which endpoint by adding a property (fromLocation) from state to the app component but the map renders only that of the hard coded values

Comment: How do I solve this?

Comment: I have solved this Map rendering problem too but I'll revise my code based on all these suggestions to make things a bit cleaner. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`defualProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for App component, and then if you don't pass latitude and longitude to the component it will use default values.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

App.defaultProps = {
    latitude: 12.917137,
    longitude: 77.622791,
}
```

Comment: Thanks @oliver.voron. I have solved this issue but yours is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: The pressing issue now is how to render the map properly based on the coords as of now, its still using the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the default Props as @oliver.voron mentioned, or do something as simple as:

```
const latitude = this.props.latitude || 'defaultLatitude';
const longitude = this.props.longitude || 'defaultLongitude';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render your `App` component like this:

```
const { lat, lng } = this.state.mLocation;
return (
    <App latitude={lat} longitude={lng}/>
);
```

Then in your `App` component if those values are `undefined` it'll fallback to default values.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            latitude: this.props.latitude || 123.45 // default value
            longitude: this.props.longitude || 456.78 // default value
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
        fetch('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + latitude + ',' + longitude +
            // other code...
    }
}
```